# Tips for doing Lückentests/Cloze tests?

Tags: learning, resource

This form of test is very commonly used as an entrance exam to preparatory courses all over Germany. Hence, the question is, how can one properly prepare for it? Here is an example:

> [image]
>
> Mut zur Lücke B2

Comment: Ehm hope this would be allowed. This was something I was searching when I started and wouldäve been helpful for it to exist somewhere. There is certainly a number of really curious german learners who also have this exam in their way, so if we could onboard them onto this site too, that'd be great

Comment: In my view one shouldn't learn a language with the goal of passing Lückentext exams. The goal should be to master the grammar and vocabulary, an then being able to solve Lückentexts is a useful byproduct.

Comment: I believe one has to go beyond simply knowing language as intermediate level to be able to do these type of tests well @RHa

Comment: Wenn die Frage wenigstens transkribiert wäre, so dass Suchmaschinen den Text erkennen und wiedererkennen könnten.

Answer (score 1):

These are just my ideas and experiences from preparing for these tests for some exams which I was unfortunately unable to write due to visa delays.

I used the book Mut zur Lücke B2 Niveau for practice. In it, I did the following method of study with my friend.

1. I attempted the test under a time limit
2. All the words I didn't understand, I made into flash cards in a flashcard app called Anki (Free on android)
3. Any grammatical question I had, I put on stackexchange.

After going carefully over my mistakes, I repeated again.

Here are some points which I think may help anyone attempting such a test.

1. You don't have to fill the words one after another, if you get stuck keep reading on and come back. Read till the end of sentence and start again.
2. Since we are given a cue on the first few letter of word, identify the word type for an easier time filling. For example, all those words in middle of sentence with a capital letter at beginning are nouns, and when answering we have to keep in mind the noun endings in dative and genitive case.

Here are some word type specific ideas:

1. Adjectives

1.1.If you have a noun with multipile adjectives, and ending of one of the adjectives are given and ending of another is not, the ending of one given will be same as ending of another..

2. Nouns

2.1. Certain noun endings will always fix the gender of noun. For example nouns ending with ung,keit and schaft are almost always feminine.
2.2. Note that countries are often genderless, and hence we don't use articles with them unless they have adjectives [More details](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74915/using-definite-articles-with-countries-when-adjectives-are-present)

3. Artikeln

3.1. If ending of noun is s, then most probably it is gentivie case

3.2. If ending of noun is n, then most probably it is dative case

3.3. Concepts have null artikeln. [See this post and comment thread](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/75026/51342)

4. General tip

4.1. Read the title of the Cloze text, often word from that will be used for answering the blanks. And, sometimes other words in the blanks would be used repeatedly.

4.2. Some Cloze tests have this phenomena where the length of characters of the missing part of a word is same or double as that of the characters of word that is given. This can be helpful in finding the answer at times.

---

## Reading strategies.

1. Read from beginning to end ignoring blanks you can't get: This is how I normally do it and most helpful.

For example, I read once along and trz fill as I go, then do again.

2.. Speak out what is written in your mind. Sometimes, it seems way easier to figure out what is grammatical from non grammatical when the thing is said aloud.

---

## Posts on things that tripped me up working through "Mut zur Luecke"

1. [Ein as one of](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74882/understanding-usage-of-eine-einer-to-mean-one-of-the?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C38.3032)
2. [Figuring out if noun is plural or sing](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76110/verb-conjugation-when-a-noun-is-written-same-way-in-singular-and-plural)
3. [Sentence starting with a verb in indikativ](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75931/starting-sentence-with-a-verb-but-doesnt-seem-like-an-imperative-sentence-or-qu)
4. [Usage of und](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75838/usage-of-und-with-an-adjective-and-noun)
5. Very very important : [Verbal bracketting](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70238/definite-article-used-in-beginning-of-a-sentence)
6. [Adverb insertion between  article and noun](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74889/distinguishing-between-adjective-and-adverb-for-word-inserted-between-article-an)
7. [Gender of stuff in quotations](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74870/how-to-figure-out-gender-of-things-in-quotation)
8. Country endings: [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69151/definite-articles-before-countries?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C18.7243),  [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74915/using-definite-articles-with-countries-when-adjectives-are-present?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C14.4102)
9. Relative clause object identification:  [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76235/relative-clause-when-object-in-main-clause-has-a-gentive-modifier) ,  [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/76233/relative-clause-ambiguity-in-object-referred)
10. [erstmal vs erstmals](https://hinative.com/questions/11113248)
11. [Coupla verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74813/werden-takes-nominative-case-or-does-it)