# Usage of "und" with an adjective and noun

Tags: sentence-structure

> Betrieben und verwaltet werden der Aufbau und die Erweiterung des Netzwerks von Biosphärenreservaten durch das UNESCO-Programm "Der Mensch und die Biosphäre". In Deutschland gibt es derzeit 15 anerkannte Biosphärenreservate.

Could someone explain what is going on with the first "und" in the above. To my understanding of how "und" works, we pair two different nouns. But, in the above, verwaltet seems to be an adjective. So, how can we pair with Betreiben?

Comment: You misread the first word.It's *betrieben*, not *betreiben*.

Comment: Etwas mit dem Link scheint schief gegangen zu sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off: The "Adjektiv" in the title is misleading. There are no *Adjektive* (adjectives) involved here.

Here "und" joins two *Verben* (verbs) in *Partizip* (participle) form. In fact there are 4 activities described:

> Betrieben und verwaltet werden der Aufbau und die Erweiterung

equals:

> Betrieben wird der Aufbau *plus*
> Verwaltet wird der Aufbau *plus*
> Betrieben wird die Erweiterung *plus*
> Verwaltet wird die Erweiterung

And all this is contracted to:

> (Betrieben und verwaltet) werden (der Aufbau und die Erweiterung)

The general rule is: "und" connects two equal things. In your example this is "Verb *und* Verb" first and "Nomen und Nomen" second. In your other [thread regarding "und"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75839/um-vs-und-in-l%C3%BCckentext-confusion) it would have had to connect two main sentences - which weren't there and hence "und" was wrong there.

Comment: Note that the conjugated verb in the sentence is actually "werden", because it is in passive voice, hence "betrieben" and "verwaltet" come in Partizip form.