# Starting sentence with a verb but doesn't seem like an imperative sentence or question.....?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Hilft der finanzielle Beitrag, die Not in den armen Ländern zu lindern, ist es mit Sicherheit gut investiert. Leider sind jedoch in vielen dieser unterentwickelten Läder die Regierungen und viele ihrer Beamten korrupt.

Could someone explain how "Hilft" is used in the above paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a combination of a Hauptsatz (main clause) and a Nebensatz (sub clause), but in a slightly unusual order. Typically, the main clause is put first, followed by the sub clause:

> Ich gehe gerne in dieses Restaurant, weil es dort meine Lieblingspizza gibt.

But it's perfectly fine to put the sub clause first, for example to put emphasis on it:

> Weil es dort meine Lieblingspizza gibt, gehe ich gerne in dieses Restaurant.

In your example the sub clause comes before the main clause, and the sub clause is somewhat shortened as well:

> Hilft der finanzielle Beitrag, die Not in den armen Ländern zu lindern, ist es mit Sicherheit gut investiert.

is a shorter way of saying

> Wenn der finanzielle Beitrag hilft, die Not in den armen Ländern zu lindern, ist es mit Sicherheit gut investiert.

And in the "default order" you could say

> Es ist mit Sicherheit gut investiert, wenn der finanzielle Beitrag hilft, die Not in den armen Ländern zu lindern.

There's also a slight incongruency between the subject of the sub clause ("der finanzielle Beitrag") and the subject of the main clause that refers to it ("es"). Technically, you'd need to say

> Er (der Beitrag) ist mit Sicherheit gut investiert, wenn der finanzielle Beitrag hilft, die Not in den armen Ländern zu lindern.

Comment: I'm not sure I would interpret it that way. It is a subclause, but I'd call it something other than a normal subclause since the word order only applies to a conditional. To my mind, the fact that the verb comes first frames it as a question, and the next clause tells you what happens if the answer is yes. This phrasing does not translate into English, but something like it possible: "Should the financial contribution help ... in poor countries, it is certainly well invested." The first clause is in the form of a question, "Should the financial contribution help ... in poor countries?"